# HTML - How to store information in a HTML tag as attribute value?

Tags: html, syntax, attributes

I do have an internal website, which has the function of an `video & audio library`. My visitors are able to download 2 kind of files from this website.

1. Video
2. Audio Only.

The source of these videos are coming from different external locations. The file extensions are different, like `.webm`, `.M4A`, `.tgpp` etc.

I know that most of them are still working, if I change the extension of the files to `.MP4`. So to make this website more easier for my visitors, regarding the different formats, I decided to offer only `.MP4` format.

Means, the client downloads a `.MP4` file, even the orginal files has the exstensions of `.WEBM` or `.M4A`.

---

It is not an issue to do that. But what I want to do is, to still keep these informations for troubleshootings in the future, I would like to store the real / orginal filetype in the HTML element.

**Question:**

Which attribute name can I use for my purpose? Is there anything existing for doing this?

For better understanding, I show it with the an attribute name `StoreInformation`:

```
<table id="id_TopTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="get-download.php?Source=Example.MP4" StoreInformation='Source_West, M4A, AudioEncoding Aac'><B>Click this</B></a>

    </td>
  </tr>
```

**Short explanation:**

- User downloads an example.mp4 file.
- The attribute `StoreInformation` stores these informations, which has meaning of:  *The file comes orginally form the Source in West, its a M4A with Audio AAc encoding.*

Comment: Why don't you just add another attribute on your link?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Comment: @JamesAMohler How do you mean, could you make an example please?

Comment: `<a href="get-download.php?Source=Example.MP4&amp;StoreInformation=Source_West,...`

Comment: @JamesAMohler Please not. This is horrible to read :-) but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So add `data-` in front of it and you have a data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best approach is to use data attributes, it would be:

```
<a href="get-download.php?Source=Example.MP4" data-information='Source_West, M4A, AudioEncoding Aac'><B>Title 1</B></a>
```

This way you can retrieve the information by using the property dataset of the element in js:

let information = element.dataset.information

for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly valid to add as a new attribute, but I would rather have a more descriptive name and better separation so that you can easily read this information and turn it into something useful:

```
<a href="something" data-format="webv" data-encoding="Aac">Content</a>
```

the `data-*` are [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) standard for custom data attributes.

You could even use the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) function to create this attribute into the html with javascript dynamically, like the following snippet:

```
document.querySelector("a").setAttribute("data-format", "webv");
```

And retrieving:

```
console.log(document.querySelector("a").getAttribute("data-format"));
```